# Sort array of images with mootools and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, mootools

I'm trying to sort an array of images by dragging and dropping them. 
If the dragged image (cur) comes before the image I drop it on (next), I want I want the images up to next to move back one. Else, I want the images from next to cur-1 to move forward one.

As far as I can tell my logic is correct, but dragging backwards (next < cur) doesn't always work properly. Sometimes it places an image on top of another one, or at the end of the array, or extends the array by one.

My brain has gone numb, so help please...

The html/javascript,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UI Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="MooTools-Core-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MooTools-More-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/UI.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="debug_area">debug area</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Areas and placeholders
        //divs
        var searchArea = new Element('div', {
            id: 'search_area'
        });

        var resultsArea = new Element('div', {
            id: 'results_area'
        });

        var resultsOverflow = new Element('div', {
            id: 'results_overflow'
        });

        var pinnedArea = new Element('div', {
            id: 'pinned_area'
        });

        var pinnedOverflow = new Element('div', {
            id: 'pinned_overflow'
        });

        var timeweatherArea = new Element('div', {
            id: 'timeweather_area'
        });

        var appArea = new Element('div', {
            id: 'app_area'
        });

        var videoArea = new Element('div', {
            id: 'video_area'
        });

        //THUMBNAIL STUFF
        var numResults = 0;
        var arrResults = [];
        var numPinned = 0;
        var arrPinned = [];
        var playlist = [];

        var drops = [];
        drops.push(resultsArea);
        drops.push(pinnedArea);

        var reorderImages = function(array){
            for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                array[i].setStyle('top', 100*((i-(i%2))/2));
                array[i].setStyle('left', 100*(i%2));           
            }
        };

        var images = [];
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            var image = new Element('img', {
                id: 'image_'+i,
                class: 'draggable',
                src: 'res/vid/thumbs/'+(i+1)+'-thumb.jpeg',
                alt: 'Image',
                height: '100',
                width: '100',
                position: 'absolute',
                styles:{
                    visibility: 'visible'
                }
            });

            images.push(image);
            arrResults.push(image);

            var mouseX=0,mouseY=0;
            image.makeDraggable({
                droppables: drops,
                container: searchArea,

                onStart: function(draggable){
                    ////$('debug_area').set('html', 'start: '+draggable.id);
                },

                onEnter: function(draggable, droppable){                        
                    ////$('debug_area').set('html', 'entered '+droppable.id);
                },

                onLeave: function(draggable, droppable){
                    ////$('debug_area').set('html', 'left '+droppable.id);
                    if(droppable.id == 'results_area'){
                        draggable.inject(searchArea);
                        draggable.setStyle('top', searchArea.get('top'));
                        draggable.setStyle('left', searchArea.get('left'));
                    }
                },

                onDrop: function(draggable, droppable){
                    ////$('debug_area').set('html', 'dropped in '+droppable.id);
                    var string;
                    var val;
                    if(droppable){
                        string = draggable.id;
                        val = string.replace('image_', '').toInt();
                    }

                    if(droppable.id == 'pinned_area'){
                        if(arrResults.indexOf(draggable) != -1)
                            arrResults.erase(draggable);
                        if(arrPinned.indexOf(draggable) == -1){
                            arrPinned.push(draggable);
                            val = arrPinned.indexOf(draggable);
                        }

                        draggable.inject(pinnedOverflow);
                        draggable.setStyle('float', 'right');
                        reorderImages(arrResults);
                        reorderImages(arrPinned);
                        ////$('debug_area').set('html', arrPinned.length +' / '+arrResults.length +' = '+ arrPinned.indexOf(draggable));
                    }else if(droppable.id == 'results_area'){
                        if(arrPinned.indexOf(draggable) != -1)
                            arrPinned.erase(draggable);

                        if(arrResults.indexOf(draggable) == -1){
                            arrResults.push(draggable);
                            val = arrResults.indexOf(draggable);
                            draggable.inject(resultsOverflow);
                        }else{
                            //code for sorting
                            var cur, next;
                            var x=draggable.getPosition().x, y=draggable.getPosition().y;
                            for(i=0;i<arrResults.length;i++){
                                var nextX = arrResults[i].getPosition().x, nextY = arrResults[i].getPosition().y;

                                if((x-x%100)/100 == (nextX-nextX%100)/100){
                                    if((y-y%100)/100 == (nextY-nextY%100)/100){
                                        cur = arrResults.indexOf(draggable);
                                        next = i;

                                        $('debug_area').set('html',arrResults[i].get('id')+' '+cur+' '+next+' '+arrResults.length);
                                        if(cur < next){
                                            for(j=cur+1;j<=next;j++){
                                                var temp = arrResults[j];
                                                arrResults[j-1] = temp;
                                            }

                                            arrResults[next] = draggable;
                                            break;
                                        }else if(cur > next){
                                            for(j=next;j<cur;j++){
                                                var temp = arrResults[j];
                                                arrResults[j+1] = temp;
                                            }

                                            arrResults[next] = draggable;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //draggable.setStyle('float', 'right');
                        reorderImages(arrResults);
                        reorderImages(arrPinned);


                        ////$('debug_area').set('html', arrPinned.length +' / '+arrResults.length +' = '+ arrResults.indexOf(draggable));
                    }
                }

            });
            image.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
            image.setStyle('top', 100*((i-(i%2))/2));
            image.setStyle('left', 100*(i%2));
        }
        resultsOverflow.adopt(images);

        var refreshThumbs = function(){
            var source;
            for(i=0;i<arrResults.length;i++){
                source = arrResults[i].get('src');
                source = source.split('?');
                arrResults[i].set('src', source[0]+'?'+ new Date().getTime());
            }

            for(i=0;i<arrPinned.length;i++){
                source = arrPinned[i].get('src');
                source = source.split('?');
                arrPinned[i].set('src', source[0]+'?'+ new Date().getTime());
            }
        };

        refreshThumbs.periodical(10000);

        //MASTER AREA INJECTION 
        resultsOverflow.inject(resultsArea);
        resultsArea.inject(searchArea);
        pinnedOverflow.inject(pinnedArea);
        pinnedArea.inject(searchArea);
        searchArea.inject(appArea);
        videoArea.inject(appArea);
        appArea.inject(document.body);

        window.addEvent('domready', function(){

        });

        window.addEvent('load', function(){

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The css is fine (I think) but here it is anyway, http://pastebin.com/xQ8ZrRmw

Here's the JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/L4tgh25a/

UPDATE 1:
Changing,

```
else if(cur > next){
    for(j=next;j<cur;j++){
        var temp = arrResults[j];
        arrResults[j+1] = temp;
    }

    arrResults[next] = draggable;
    break;
}
```

to,

```
else if(cur > next){
    arrResults.splice(cur, 1);
    arrResults.splice(next, 0, draggable);
    break;
}
```

fixes the problem. Why? I'm quite sure my algorithm was correct (but not accounting for the beginning and end of the array, which doesn't matter because the problem happens in the middle anyway). Was my algorithm wrong or was it a javascript thing?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle with this? You could also use More's [Sortables](http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.5.1/Drag/Sortables).

Comment: add the jsfiddle. I'm not using sortables because I want to do different drag stuff as well.

Comment: Found the solution, but I'm still confused as to why the original code doesn't work.